# Convert mailchimp double opt in to single

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to create a single opt in mailchimp form.

I think they've removed the check box to disable double in verification. wufoo.com creates a form that integrates with mailchimp, it works, but it's their form, and shows a large reference to their site.

Can I modify the mailchimp-generated form to create a single opt effect as well?

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
  #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
  /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
     We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//mynewhealingsite.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1234a5678b80av686fd86a7d7&amp;id=269cdca319" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
  <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_1234a5678b80av686fd86a7d7_269cdca319" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Answer (score 1):

On Nov. 3, 2017, MailChimp added single opt-in functionality to signup forms. Here is [the announce](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/single-opt-in-vs.-double-opt-in).

Here is [the instruction](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/growth/change-list-name-and-defaults) on how to switch between single opt-in and double opt-in. It doesn't change form HTML, so there is no need to change existing markup.

Comment: Good to know.  Consider expanding your answer by showing the code required to solve the questioner's problem.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Added a note about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All forms provided directly by MailChimp, including their embed code option, only allow double opt-in. So their is no modification of their original form(s) capable of providing single opt-in.

This guide from their docs denotes this: [Double Opt-In Signup Form FAQ's](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/double-opt-in-signup-form-faqs)

That said, their API can be used to build out custom single opt-in forms. Alternatively, if that is not an option finding a form integration provider like Wufoo as you've done, that have pre-built a single opt-in solution, may be best.

This page from their API 3.0 docs goes over working with subscribers: [Manage Subscribers](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/)